# clojure function behaves like a symbol when called without argument

Tags: clojure

I get the following weird behaviour from a clojure function: When I call it with one argument it seems as if it is a function, when I call it without arguments it appears to be a symbol. Any ideas how this can be?

this is what happens in the interpreter:

```
=> (input-updatef -1)
```

> ArityException Wrong number of args (1) passed to: modelingutils/create-process-level/input-updatef--2954  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)

and when I try calling it without any argument:

```
=> (input-updatef)
```

> ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: Symbol  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)

Thx!

Comment: Does `input-updatef` call `symbol` anywhere?

Comment: Can you post the implementation of `input-updatef`?

Comment: If you look at the stack trace that goes with that exception, you'll see that the error isn't in the top level invocation of `input-updatef`, but is somewhere deeper in the call stack.

Comment: Without more information about the implementation of input-updatef It will be rather difficult to answer this question.

Comment: You need to provide the actual source for the function. Without it, we have to make a lot of assumptions and guesses which will likely be more misleading than helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Answering "how this can be":

```
user=> (defn foo [] ('foo))
#'user/foo
user=> (foo 1)
ArityException Wrong number of args (1) passed to: user/foo  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
user=> (foo)
ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: Symbol  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
```

Of course your `input-updatef` situation may be more subtle, but it is at least clear that

1. either the actual `input-updatef` function has no unary overload or it has one, but when you call it it ends up calling a function that has no unary overload with just one argument;
2. it has a nullary overload;
3. calling the nullary overload results in a call to a symbol with no arguments.

Also, based on the `modelingutils/create-process-level/input-updatef--2954` part of your error message it seems to me that `input-updatef` might be a "local function" – created using `letfn` or introduced as the value of a `let` binding – returned at some point from a function called `create-process-level`. Here's an example of what that could look like:

```
user=> (defn foo
         ([]
           ('foo))
         ([x]
           (letfn [(f [])]
             (f x))))
#'user/foo
user=> (foo 1)
ArityException Wrong number of args (1) passed to: user/foo/f--4  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
user=> (foo)
ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: Symbol  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
```

Using

```
(defn foo
  ([]
    ('foo))
  ([x]
    (let [f (fn [])]
      (f x))))
```

would have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, both answers helped.

I did not post the definition, because it contained a complex macro.. 
The problem was that I called the macro from a normal function and supplied an argument (an ff function) to this macro from the argument list of the calling function. This ff was interpreted as a symbol at macro evaluation time -- this is what caused the strange behaviour.

Solution: I changed the outer calling function into a macro, and unquoted ff in the argument list of the called macro.